# How to compare passportjs auto generated hash password with login password?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I am using passportJs for user authentication .Also I am using passport-local-mongoose which convert password into hashed password and store hash and salt in DB . While log in I create login-strategy which takes email and password . So, how can I compare the **password(hash & salt) stored in DB** with the password which user enter while login .

**Userschema**

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: "User",
  },
});
```

**signup route**

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      role: req.body.role,
    });
    const newUser = await User.register(user, req.body.password);
    // console.log(newUser);
    res.send(newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.send(error);
  }
});
```

**local-strategy**

```js
passport.use(
  "local-login",
  new localStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
    },
    async function (email, password, done) {
      await User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        if (!user) {
          console.log("Incorrect username.");
        }
       
        bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password),//unable to get user.password because it store in hash
          function (err, res) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            if (res === false) {
              console.log("Incorrect password.");
            }

            return user;
          };
      });
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
passport.use(
  "local-login",
  new localStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
    },
    async function (email, password, done) {
      await User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        if (!user) {
          console.log("Incorrect username.");
        }
       
        bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.passwordHash),//replace passwordHash with the key which was to used to store Hashed Password
          function (err, res) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            if (res === false) {
              console.log("Incorrect password.");
            }

            return user;
          };
      });
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: I didn't get it . Which key you are talking about ?

Comment: "password": "$2a$10$BZQdTI.O5flNQIua8di1Pe/6XzeVkMC0lbJU2zswnWn/yZpZWdBJa"

password is The document name in database

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using await and callback both at the same time. Check the below code:

```
passport.use(
    "local-login",
    new localStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
      },
      async function (email, password, done) {
       try {
        const user =  await User.findOne({ email: email });
            console.log(user);
            if (!user) {
            console.log("Incorrect username.");
            }
       
       const passwordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordHash);//unable to get user.password because it store in hash
            if (passwordMatched) {
              return user;
            }
            else  {
              console.log("Incorrect password.");
            }

       } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
       }  
    }
));
```

Comment: I am using passport local mongoose package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-mongoose) which simplifies building username and password login with Passport. It automatically hash the password and save into the db in the form of hash and the salt .

Comment: Does it save for you? Have you checked the user details coming from DB? DOes it contains the password?

Comment: after register it user will be 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60cb58c158f12b47e4c1c4cd"),
    "role" : "User",
    "username" : "wxyz",
    "email" : "wxyz@gmail.com",
    "salt" : "6780c29f281edf4ebc505d5a14459245314a1ccef1fc4634855a0f719e868059",
    "hash" : "17f46c07631daef342644b7c244c3....",
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: Yeah it save in the form of (hash and salt) . 
If I go with your suggestion then password will be saved explicitly with hash and salt . And I dont want anyone can see the password . Then what is the need of hash password . 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60cc3beb153f5a3874db8f93"),
    "role" : "User",
    "username" : "abc",
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "password" : "1234567",
    "salt" : "974602d5b997c35847f40453e0edf744c30f6327c425214fd47c2063bee9cd1d",
    "hash" : "c08ba70d9a0ec0b618db09d7bb64906421f15da06b40f5fff0..."
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: Just updated the code check now. If you don't want to show hash one that the above package make sense.

Comment: Not working ..
 `(node:10300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash arguments required ` .
` const passwordMatched = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)`   This is not valid format

Comment: It should work now, the reason is sync doesn't give the promise. and when we use async/await try to always use the try/catch.

Comment: It shows same error . We are not getting hash with the user . It only display into the db .  If I console log user it gives `{
  role: 'User',
  _id: 60cc4281bacc740d48279d4b,
  username: 'abc',
  email: 'abc@gmail.com',
  __v: 0
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233919/discussion-between-apoorva-chikara-and-prathamesh-mungekar).